# Downloaded file is 0 bytes, what is wrong with it?

Tags: java, groovy, struts2

Need help in figuring out, why the downloaded file  size is 0 bytes? On click of the download button it the page pops up a save or open dialog box, when I choose save with some location  is saves the file, but it is a empty file. Whats wrong with it?

JSP file

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="/csm/download.action" >
    <input type="hidden" id="absFileName" name="absFileName" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnDownloadConfig" value="Download Configuration"/>
</form>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="download" class="com.abc.csm.actions.DownloadConfiguration">
    </action>
```

My code for download

```
String filePath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
filePath+=executionResponse

def splits=filePath.split("/")

cfgfileFileName=splits[splits.length-1]

println filePath+", "+cfgfile+", "+cfgfileFileName+", "+executionResponse

File f=new File(filePath)

println("Does file Exists? "+f.exists())

InputStream  inputStream = new FileInputStream(f)

response.setContentType("APPLICATION/xml")

response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+cfgfileFileName+"\"")
```

My ouput in console

```
E:\Tomcat 6\webapps\csm\files//1123/Infa9_1_csmclientbeetle.xml, Infa9_1_csmclientbeetle.xml, files//1123/Infa9_1_csmclientbeetle.xml
Does file Exists? true
```

My file location in the tomcat webapps

```
E:\Tomcat 6\webapps\csm\files\1123
```

**Update**

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459799/downloaded-zip-file-returns-zero-has-0-bytes-as-size) that helped me

This is what i did with InputStream

```
FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(f)
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024]
    int len = 0
    while ((len = ins.read(buf)) >= 0)
    {
        out.write(buf, 0, len)
    }
    ins.close()
    out.close()
```

Comment: Does your code actually *do* anything with `inputstream`?

Comment: i am not sure why you doing all this while same can be done in more clean way using stream result (http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/stream-result.html).

Comment: @Umesh: Do you have an example, where I can look at? Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: see my updated comment. i believe you are not using real power of S2.

Comment: @Umesh: in that link it has something where it set the filename `<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="document.pdf"</param>` but in my case I need to set it dynamically

Comment: @Umesh: in that link it has something where it set the filename `<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="document.pdf"</param>` but in my case I need to set it dynamically

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: see my answer for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use S2 build in `Stream result` type to handle your download functionality in more flexible way.All you need to define `fileInputStream` in your action class which will be used to download your content.

you can set all other things in your configuration file dynamically.Here is a sample code

```
public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport{

    private InputStream fileInputStream;

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("location of your file"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

you can use stream result tin your struts.xml file

```
<action name="download" class="com.abc.csm.actions.DownloadConfiguration">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
      <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="fileABC.txt"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
   </action>
```

All the above param, inside your action tag can be set dynamically. all you need to define the properties in you action class and use them in the configuration.

e.g if you want to set content-type dynamically create a property in your action class with its getters and setters and set the values of this property inside your execute/any other method.
you need to use the dynamic property value in your struts.xml file like

```
 <action name="download" class="com.abc.csm.actions.DownloadConfiguration">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
          <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
          <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
          <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="fileABC.txt"</param>
          <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
       </action>
```

for details about the various properties than can be set inside your stream result, see the official doc

[stream-result](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/stream-result.html)

Comment: Nice full answer for a new struts2 user, good work staying all over the struts2 tag Umesh, at this rate you'll probably be the first with a silver in this tag.

Comment: @Quaternion: Thanks for compliments :)

Answer (score 4):

```
InputStream  inputStream = new FileInputStream(f)
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/xml")
response.addHeader(
  "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+cfgfileFileName+"\"")
```

is that all? Where are you sending the file? You may miss something like

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your writer instance:

```
myWriter.flush();
```

Comment: What writer? and what difference will that make?

Comment: When writing data to file or somewhere else, like sockets or something you should wrap your input stream to something more high-level, like FileWriter class to make it easier to work on. FileWriter class has a method called flush(), which instantly writes the data you have in your stream to the file, socket, etc. This is needed because data isn't always written the same time it's received, a stream has it in a buffer, so to make sure the data gets written you should use the flush() method.

Comment: The `flush()` happens automatically at `out.close()`. Adding an explicit one won't solve this problem.